# Zen-Cart Credit Card declined

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, zen-cart

I am using Zen cart in my eCommerce website and SecurePay module to process the payment. But When I enter a good and valid credit card for payment, it is giving me error that:

Your card has been declined. Please re-enter your card information, try another card, or contact the store owner for assistance.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new store?  Have you ever processed a real card payment before with this set-up or are you testing for the first time?  What did securepay say about the attempted payment when you logged in there to look at the attempted payment?